# File's Owner Outlet vs View's Outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a xib and few buttons on it. I am trying to create connect the outlet to the properties in header file. I noticed there are two kind of outlets. One is File Owner's outlet and the other is view's outlet. Do I have to connect them all or just one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect the File Owner's outlet.

[image]